# How do I setup my JQuery Mobile MultiPage Navigation in my hybrid application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, navigation

The JQuery Mobile Pages and Navigation Demos and Documenation has a lot of great info but I am still not 100% clear on best practices when navigating between pages found on a single temple.

Background: I am creating a hybrid mobile app with Cordova, JQuery Mobile and Wordpress. My index.html file contains 6 pages `data-role="page"`. Each page has a Header/Nav with three links (Home, Artist, and Show Info). Throughout the pages there are other Links and Buttons they all take you to one of the list pages though.

Best Case Senerio: Is it possible to create an eventListener(s) that controls were the user goes and the type of transition. I am trying to make the app as stable as possible so if the user gets tap happy with the nav there are minimal bugs.

I actually have a few questions (below is an example of my code):

1. Does each nav item (6 pages 3 per page = 18 links) have to have a unique ID or can I use classes?
2. What are best practices? Using the href='' and transition attributes in a link or can I create an eventListener in my main JS file that handles the navigation and possibly passing data between pages (but not a deal breaker)

Below is my first try with creating on.('click') events to the nav items via class name and the ui-active-page class. Any info and or examples that are not the Jquery Mobile docs/demos would be great.

Example of my index.html with two pages outlined:

```
<div data-role="page" id="show-info" class="ui-body-c">
        <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;" >
            <h3 class="cyan-header-text cyan-logo-text-h3" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 10px;">OHIO</h3>
            <a style="color:#00b3ba;" href="http://mywebsite.com/online-ticket-sales/" data-icon="ticket" class="buy-ticket-button ui-btn-right ui-icon-ticket ui-icon-left">BUY TICKETS</a>
            <div class="logo-title-wrap">
                <div class="logo-wrap">
                    <img class="header-logo" src="images/cti_header-logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="title-wrap">
                    <h1 class="cyan-header-text cyan-logo-text-h1" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top:  5px;margin-bottom: 5px;
">INVITATIONAL</h1>
                    <h3 class="h3-header-sub" style="font-size: 12px;margin: 0px 0px;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: 200;
">May 1st, 2020 - May 3rd, 2020</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="blue-button home-button" href="#" data-transition="slidefade">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a class="blue-button artist-refresh artist-button" href="#" data-transition="slidefade">ARTIST</a></li>
                    <li><a class="blue-button show-button" href="#" data-transition="slidefade">SHOW INFO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
       </div>
</div> <!--END OF PAGE 1-->

<div data-role="page" id="cyan-home" class="ui-body-c">

    <!-- RTIST header -->
    <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;" >
        <h3 class="cyan-header-text cyan-logo-text-h3" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 10px;">OHIO</h3>
        <a style="color:#00b3ba;margin:4px 5px 0 0;padding:6px 3px 6px 30px;" href="http://mywebsite.com/online-ticket-sales/" data-icon="ticket" class="buy-ticket-button ui-btn-right ui-icon-ticket ui-icon-left">BUY TICKETS</a>
        <div class="logo-title-wrap">
            <div class="logo-wrap">
                <img class="header-logo" src="images/cti_header-logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">
                <h1 class="cyan-header-text cyan-logo-text-h1" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top:  5px;margin-bottom: 5px;
">INVITATIONAL</h1>
                <h3 class="h3-header-sub" style="font-size: 12px;margin: 0px 0px;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: 200;
">May 1st, 2020 - May 3rd, 2020</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="cyan-button home-button" href="#" data-transition="slidefade">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a class="cyan-button artist-refresh artist-button" href="#" data-transition="slidefade">ARTIST</a></li>
                <li><a class="cyan-button show-button" href="#" data-transition="slidefade">SHOW INFO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->
  <!-- CYAN ARTIST body -->
        <div data-role="content" id="artist-listview">
         </div>
</div><!--END OF PAGE 2-->
```

main.js snippet of me trying to setup the navigation listeners:

```
function setupMainNav() {
    console.log("Settign Up SUB NAV");


    $('.ui-page-active .show-button').on('click', function () {
        console.log("In the show info click");
        $.mobile.changePage("#show-info", {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });


    $('.ui-page-active .home-button').on('click', function () {
        console.log("In the show info click");
        $.mobile.changePage("#home", {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });


    $('#artistContactButton').on('click', function () {
        console.log("Show Contact Form");
        $.mobile.changePage("#artist-contactpage", {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });


    $('div.ui-page-active a.artist-button').on('click', function () {
        console.log("artist button click");
        $.mobile.changePage("#cyan-home", {
            transition: "slide"
        });

    });

    $('#show_link').on('click', function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#cyan-home", {
            transition: "slide"
        });

    });

    $('#shop_link').on('click', function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#shop-home", {
            transition: "slide"
        });

    });


}
```

Comment: 1- Use an external Navbar; same navbar will be shared among all pages. 2- It depends, navigation only? there's no need for listeners. Passing/processing data, etc, yes, you should add listeners.

Comment: https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-persistent/index.html